# Play video iframe with reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, iframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwsMG.png)There is an issue. I have a slider which contains 2 images and 1 video, I embedded video in an iframe. The question is how can I hide 2 buttons (next and prev) of slider when I play video and show back when video is paused.

Comment: which slider library are you using?

Comment: i'm using react-slick noww

Comment: Please [do not post pictures of text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), put that text in your post (with appropriate markup).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [this component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player) wich has built-in onPlay and onStop functions that would allow you to display or not the arrows from the slider.

You can achieve this by using a state for the arrow attribute wich would be set to false when the video is playing and to true when it's not.

Here is an exemple:

```
  <ReactPlayer 
    onPlay={this.handlePlay()}
    onPause={this.handlePause()}
    url='yourvideourl' />
```

Note: handlePlay() should set the state of your arrow state variable to true and handlePause() to false.

Comment: It's work for me, thank you so much.